# Trigger useEffect with anotherComponents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have 2 components, the Favorites component, makes a request to the api and maps the data to Card.

I also have a BtnFav button, which receives an individual item, and renders a full or empty heart according to a boolean.

Clicking on the BtnFav render removes a certain item from the favorites database.

What I need is that in the Favorites component, when I click on the BtnFavs component, the useEffect of Favorites is triggered again to bring the updated favorites.

How can i solve this? I have partially solved it with a global context(favoritesUser), but is there any other neater alternative?

The data flow for now would be something like this:

Favorites component fetches all the complete data and passes it to the Card component, the Card component passes individual data to the BtnFavs component.

```
Favorites Component:

const fetchWines = async () => {
    try {
      const vinos = await axios.get(`/api/favoritos/${id}`);
      const arrVinos = vinos.data.map((vino) => {
        return vino.product;
      });
      setVinosFavs(arrVinos);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchWines();
  }, [favoritesUser]);



  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Mis favoritos</h1>

      <Card listWines={vinosFavs} />
    </div>
  );
```

```
BtnFavs:



const handleClickFav = (e) => {
    if (!boton) {
      axios.post("/api/favoritos/add", { userId, productId }).then((data) => {
        setBoton(true);

        return;
      });
    }
    axios.put("/api/favoritos/delete ", { userId, productId }).then((data) => {
      setBoton(false);

      setFavoritesUser(data);
    });
  };
```

What I need is that in the Favorites component, when I click on the BtnFavs component, the useEffect of Favorites is triggered again to bring the updated favorites.

How can i solve this? I have partially solved it with a global context(favoritesUser), but is there any other neater alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you want is called a callback function, just like the `onClick` of a button. You pass a function to your components that get executed given a condition. If you want `fetchWines` to be called again, then just pass the function in as a prop.

Favorites Component:

```
<Card listWines={vinosFavs} refresh={fetchWines} />
```

Card Component

```
<BtnFavs onDelete={refresh} ... />
```

BtnFavs Component

```
onDelete();
```

You can name it whatever you want, but generally callbacks will be named like `on<condition>`.

---

If you really wanted `useEffect` to be triggered then you would pass a `setState` function that set one of the dependencies, but I don't see a point in this case.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand how to use it.

My BtnFavs component receives the productId from the Card component and the userId from redux.

Then you have that method in the backend that returns true or false indicating if they have it or not. This is individual for each product.

I don't really understand how the refresh delete would work and how that would make my favorite component render again. The BtnFavs is used in other views with the same logic that I mentioned.

Comment: What makes your component render is calling a `setState` function - in this case `setVinosFavs` within `fetchWines` - which I'm assuming is the function returned from `useState` - by passing the function down to your button, your button can make the parent component re-render. If you want me to show you exactly what the code will look like, you will need to provide all of the code for all three components.

Comment: @Gabriel `refresh` and `onDelete` are just different names I gave the properties - they are both just the `fetchWines` function in this case.

Comment: Yes i will update with my code soon, i really want to know how to do it. thanks Chris

Answer (score 0):

I will share code, because this problem its normal for me, i really want to learn and improve that.

```
const Favorites = () => {
 const { favoritesUser } = useFavoritesContext();
 const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
 const id = user.id;
 const [vinosFavs, setVinosFavs] = useState([]);

 const fetchWines = async () => {
   try {
     const vinos = await axios.get(`/api/favoritos/${id}`);
     const arrVinos = vinos.data.map((vino) => {
       return vino.product;
     });
     setVinosFavs(arrVinos);
   } catch (err) {
     console.error(err);
   }
 };

 useEffect(() => {
   fetchWines();
 }, [favoritesUser]);

 return (
   <div>
     <h1>My favorits</h1>

     <Grid listVinos={vinosFavs} />
   </div>
 );
};

export default Favorites
```

```
Grid
export default function Grid({ listVinos }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className={styles.layoutDeVinos}>
        {listVinos?.map((element) => {
          return <WineCard key={element.id} vino={element} />;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
Card 

export default function WineCard({ vino }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Link to={`/products/${vino.id}`}>
          <li>
            <div className={styles.card}>
              <div
                className={styles.img1}
                style={{
                  backgroundImage: `url(${vino.images})`,
                }}
              ></div>

              <div className={styles.text}>{vino.descripcion}</div>

              <div className={styles.catagory}>
                {vino.nombre}
                <i className="fas fa-film"></i>
              </div>

              <div className={styles.views}>
                {vino.bodega}
                <i className="far fa-eye"></i>{" "}
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </Link>
        <div className="botonesUsuario">
          <BtnFavs vino={vino} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
BTN FAVS

export default function BtnFavs({ vino }) {
  const { setFavoritesUser } = useFavoritesContext();
  const [boton, setBoton] = useState(false);

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const userId = user.id;
  const productId = vino.id;

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post("/api/favoritos/verify", { userId, productId })
      .then((bool) => setBoton(bool.data));
  }, []);

  const handleClickFav = (e) => {
    if (!boton) {
      axios.post("/api/favoritos/add", { userId, productId }).then((data) => {
        setBoton(true);

        return;
      });
    }
    axios.put("/api/favoritos/delete ", { userId, productId }).then((data) => {
      setBoton(false);

      setFavoritesUser(data);
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {!user.id ? (
        <div></div>
      ) : boton ? (
        <span
          class="favIcons material-symbols-rounded"
          onClick={handleClickFav}
        >
          favorite
        </span>
      ) : (
        <span className="material-symbols-rounded" onClick={handleClickFav}>
          favorite
        </span>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```